# Can't select the files in a torrent using utorrent on mac

Tags: mac, utorrent, selection

I would like to download just a few albums from a discography and when I open the .torrent in uTorrent, the window allowing me to select different files opens but when I select the ones I need and press OK it starts dowloading the whole thing.
I also tried "skipping" the files I didn't need in the lower tab and setting the ones I wanted on "high priority", it still didn't work.

I've already done that many times before and it always worked. I'm all out of ideas to fix that problem so any help is welcome.

Thanks!

PS: It's not a magnet link either.

Comment: Have you tried going into `Preferences>ui settings>show a window that displays the files inside the torrent in advanced mode` then clicking the "**Toggle torrent view**" button until you get column headers?

Answer (score 2):

1. You've to do this before you start downloading. Get the torrent / download and add it. Immediately stop it (pause it I mean, but for MAC it is just stop) so that the download doesn't proceed beyond 0%.
2. On the "View" tab above your utorrent application screen, choose "Enable details pane"
3. You will now see a details pane appear in your utorrent. You'll see 5 tabs, "General", "Tracker", "Files", "Peers", "Speed". Select "Files" tab.
4. Now you must see all the individual files inside the package listed. If you don't, then delete torrent, files and start again from step 1.
5. Once you see them individual files, select one or many by holding down Command key. Right click and choose "Do not download".

Done. Now you can see that those files selected such will have a "skip" mentioned next to them and those continuing to download a "normal" next to them.

Don't delete the skipped files in the download directory yet. It could affect your download. Once downloaded fully, and you've chosen to stop and remove the torrent from utorrent (if not seeding), then you can delete the unwanted files.